# what is the concept behind memory initialization for Array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
String a[]=null;
    if(a[0]!=null)
    {
        System.err.println("dd-1");
    }

    if(a!=null)
        {
        System.err.println("dd-2");
        }
    }
```

In first if condtion its throwing null pointer exception, but in second if condition its not throwing null pointer exception? can anyone please explain me the same? is there is any concept behind this on Heap memory allocation.

also i got to know the problem becauese of Missing memory allocation,String a[]=new String.[10]; please expalain the concept?

Comment: thank you all.i got it cleary now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first if condition you are trying to access the first element in the array, even thought there is no allocation done for it.

In second condition you are just testing the reference.

(Think of it as C pointers, char *str = NULL does not allocated any thing except a pointer pointing to NULL)

```
String a[]=null;
```

No memory is allocated for the array only reference is created.

```
String a[] = new String[1]
```

Memory to hold one String object is created on the Heap and `a` points to the allocated string object.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(a[0]!=null)
```

The first condition is trying to access the first element of the array (and check if it exists). That will not work if the array does not exist (i.e. is null).

```
 if(a!=null)
```

The second condition is just checking if the array itself is null.

Memory for the array gets allocated (on the heap) when you create the array. At that time you also have to specify its size (and that will determine exactly how much memory gets allocated). The memory is also initialized with null, so you don't get garbage data for a fresh array.

Access to array elements is not just pointer arithmetic as in C, Java actually checks if the array exists and if the index is within its bounds.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, arrays are not like C, they are objects living in the heap, they do have a special type and syntax to access their elements but they are objects, if you wish to access any subindex you'll need to do something like

```
String[] a = new String[10];
```

after that, each element will be initialized in null, 0 or false depending the type of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects.  You have to create new space for them.  If you're trying to access a null reference, you'll get a `NullPointerException` every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `a[0]`, you are going to access a object (first object of the array). but `a` doesn't have any object yet. therefore first one throws a exception. But in second one, you are checking a reference. it is not an object. So `a` is equals to NULL.